# Dynamic data Google Visualization

Tags: google-visualization

I am getting the error 'Error: Argument given to addRows must be either a number or an array' when using the code below. However, when I copy the code that is being exported and hard code it, the data displays correctly. Anyone have any ideas?

The hardcoded version is this:
dataTable.addRows([
[ 'DTR V', null, 'Approval Audience Generation Invitation and Confirmation', new Date(2021, 3, 13), new Date(2021, 5, 15) ],
]);

```
  for(var i = 2; i < countRow; i++) {
      for(var ii = 0; ii < countColumn; ii++) {
          if (ii == 0) {
              
              theData += "[ '" + a.getDataTable().getValue(i, 0) + "', null, '<div class=\"ggl-tooltip\">" + a.getDataTable().getValue(i, 2) + "</div>', new Date("+ a.getDataTable().getFormattedValue(i, 3) +"), new Date("+ a.getDataTable().getFormattedValue(i, 4) +") ], "; 
              
          }
      } 
      
       dataTable.addRows(theData);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I created variables first, I didn't have the error:

```
  for(var i = 0; i < countRow; i++) {
      for(var ii = 0; ii < countColumn; ii++) {
          if (ii == 0) {

                $project = a.getDataTable().getValue(i, 0);
                $toolTip = '<div class="ggl-tooltip">' + a.getDataTable().getValue(i, 2) + '</div>';
                $dteStrt = a.getDataTable().getFormattedValue(i, 3);
                $dteStrtSplt = $dteStrt.split(",");
                $yrS = $dteStrtSplt[0];
                $moS = $dteStrtSplt[1];
                $daS = $dteStrtSplt[2];
                $dteEnd = a.getDataTable().getFormattedValue(i, 4);
                $dteEndSplt = $dteEnd.split(",");
                $yrS = $dteEndSplt[0];
                $moS = $dteEndSplt[1];
                $daS = $dteEndSplt[2];
          }

          
      } 
      
      dataTable.addRows([ [ $project, null, $toolTip, new Date($yrS, $moS, $daS), new Date($yrE, $moE, $daE) ] ]);
      
  }
```